# Load a selected option on a dynamically created `<select>`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page that saves a bunch of options (from a `<select>`). I can store the values via PHP and MySQL just fine and restore the values of those selects.

The problem comes with dynamically created selects. Through logging to the console, I can confirm the HTML of the `<select>`s has loaded properly and they function properly on screen. But none of them load the stored value.

I’ve tried using:

```
$("#selectID").val(storedVariable);
```

```js
$("#selectID").prop("selectedIndex", storedIndex);
```

```js
$("#selectID option[value=" + storedVariable + "]").prop("selected", true);
```

None of these options work. And to make matters worse, I can use the console to check the `.val()` or `.prop("selectedIndex")` and they return the proper value, but the `<option>` displayed/selected drop-down option is blank (index `0`).

Again, this is only on dynamically created selects, the ones hard-coded in work just fine.

here's the code I'm using:

file.html

```
<select id="select1">
    <option value="choice1">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="choice2">Choice 2</option>
</select>
<select id="select2"></select>
```

file.js

```
// selectedValue1 & selectedValue2 are sent from file.php
console.log(selectedValue1); // -> "choice2"
console.log(selectedValue2); // -> "choice2B"
// these work, I can verify them in the console

$("#select1").val(selectedValue1);
updateSelections();
$("#select2").val(selectedValue2);

function updateSelections() {
    $("#select2").html(function() {
        var optionChoices = "<option value='blank'>&nbsp;</option>";
        if ("#select1".val() == "choice1") {
            optionChoices += "<option value='choice1A'>Choice 1A</option>";
            optionChoices += "<option value='choice1B'>Choice 1B</option>";
            optionChoices += "<option value='choice1C'>Choice 1C</option>";
            return optionChoices;
        } else if ("#select1".val() == "choice2") {
            optionChoices += "<option value='choice2A'>Choice 2A</option>";
            optionChoices += "<option value='choice2B'>Choice 2B</option>";
            optionChoices += "<option value='choice2C'>Choice 2C</option>";        
        }
        return optionChoices;
    }, 0);
}
```

Basically selectedValue1 loads perfectly, but selectedValue2 does not.

UPDATE: Here's the actual line of code from my app that should work.

```
console.log(fieldOfStudy);
$("#selectFieldOfStudy").val(fieldOfStudy);
console.log($("#selectFieldOfStudy").val());
```

The console.log() outputs the correct stored information both times, but the value is not displayed correctly on screen.

Comment: Can you kindly take a minute to edit and include a reproducible example? ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: may be its related to when you are setting the selected attribute.

Comment: When and where are you executing these lines? We need more context around them.

Comment: Did you check if the `value` attribute of the `<option/>` does contain the correct value? It does not matter what the `<option/>` displays but what its actual `value` is. One `value` needs to match exactly the predefined value for preselecting.

Comment: @TylerRoper I added an example of the code I'm using.

Comment: @Xufox, I've checked to make sure the html of that particular select is loaded before attempting to select the value. I added the code I'm using, and you can see I first set the value of a the "hardcoded" select, and then update the options of the dynamically created select. After all that I attempt to set the dynamically created select and for some reason fail.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3, yes. Through the console I can verify the created elements contain the value I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in your code.

1. Function `updateSelections` should be defined before being used
2. `"#select1".val()` : wrap `"#select1"` into `$()`

Also consider updating `select2` each time the first `select` is modified:

```
$("#select1").on('change', updateSelections);
```

See the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/613071/

Comment: Please understand that the actual file is over 2000 lines of JS, but I did check on point #1 and it is being defined well before I call for it. As for the rest, I just simplified what I'm doing in the example above, the app works perfectly except for this one bug that I can't seem to squash.

Comment: Also, I do update all selects in the DOM every time a one is changed, the code above is from the loading function.